# Visual Studio 2010 Workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know if Visual Studio 2010 has a concept of Workspaces? Like workspaces in the eclipse IDE, not to be confused by workspaces in TFS.

I'm finding that my window is completely cluttered with tabs I only need in certain situations.

Comment: I can't believe you with 1665 rep. points tagged your own question with 3 tags: Visual, Studio and 2010 ò.Ó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm moving forward with this solution. http://www.brianschmitt.com/2010/09/save-and-change-tool-layout-in-visual.html

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is Visual Studio Window Manager which can completely customize the windows for each specific situation. I used to use it w/ VS2008. By the way I forgot the url so you'll need to google it.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio a [solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df8st53z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is effectively the same thing. [This page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-visualstudio/) describes this a bit more.